# Using Start-Process for starting a process having its full command line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, start-process

How can I use PowerShell's `Start-Process` cmdlet to start a process using its full command line (with executable path and arguments). For instance let I have the following line

```
"<dir_path>/myprog.exe" -arg1 "val1" -arg2 "val2"
```

stored on some string variable and want to run it via Start-Process.

I know that `Start-Process -FilePath '<dir_path>/myprog.exe' -ArgumentList '-arg1 "val1" -arg2 "val2"'` will work. But the point is that I don't know how to get executable's path and arguments from the full command line.

So is there some way to run process using its full command line via `Start-Process`, or if there is no such way, then how can I get file path and argument list from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need start-process? Can you invoke the executable directly?

```
& "C:\Dir 1\Dir 2\executable.exe" -arg1 "value 1" -arg2 "value 2"
```

See **help about_Operators** and for info on **&** (call) operator.

Bill

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you have your heart set on **Start-Process**? If not, you can do this:

```
Invoke-Expression "& $command"
```

where **$command** is the variable that stores the full command line.